# Azure Service Bus Subscription Filters & Pub Sub Model

Tags: azureservicebus

There is no control from the publisher that Subscriber has to use the filter to subscribe. In this case, as a subscriber a consumer can use filter or cannot use filter when subscribing to a topic. So, apart from internal systems being subscribed how can we use the Subscription Filters in Azure Service Bus to avoid creating redundant topics to isolate the messages?

Answer (score 1):

> as a subscriber a consumer can use filter or cannot use filter when subscribing to a topic.

We could create subscription and set up filter to restrict the set of messages passed to the subscription's virtual queue, and then the receivers could subscribe to the specific topic subscription to consume the filtered messages. You could refer to the following article to set up filters.

- [Create subscriptions with
  filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions#create-a-subscription)

Besides, if subscriber system (or program) is receiving messages from an existing subscription that is not created by program itself, you could do filter based on message property in your program code logic.

Comment: Thanks @Fred, I have seen this url earlier but i am not sure about the first part of your answer. I will try the sample first before I comment on this.